# How to load ui.bootstrap module by diffrent way from controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have following project configuration:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.when('/aaa',
                   {templateUrl: config.base_url + 'app/partials/aaa/index.html',
                    controller: 'AAACtrl'});
                $routeProvider.when('/bbb', 
                   {templateUrl: config.base_url + 'app/partials/bbb/index.html', 
                    controller: 'BBBCtrl'});
                $routeProvider.when('/ccc', 
                   {templateUrl: config.base_url + 'app/ccc/reportsView.html', 
                    controller: 'reportCtrl'});
                            }]);
```

You can see that I don't load `ui.bootstrap` module.

The `reportCtrl` looks like:

```
app.controller('reportCtrl',  
    ['$scope', function($scope) { /**/}
```

According to this demo [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gg7T3IpK6ZVKJsggotJy?p=preview) I want to use datepicker. However it demands to add `ui.bootstrap` module to `app`. But I don't want to add to all my project (to prevent collisions). I'm interesting to use `ui.bootstrap` module only in one controller.

I use codeigniter and each controller uses own headers.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one thing on my mind is to create different module and routeProvider. Notice that we can "extend" parent module by adding `myApp` in order to use services/directives refer to `myApp`.

```
var appReport = angular.module('myAppReport', ['myApp','ui.bootstrap']);
//                                  ^^^          ^^^        
//                             new module     extends old one

  // we just split $routerProvider
  appReport.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.when('/ccc', 
               {templateUrl: config.base_url + 'app/ccc/reportsView.html', 
                controller: 'reportCtrl'});
                        }]);
```

Therefore the `myApp` looks like:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.when('/aaa',
                   {templateUrl: config.base_url + 'app/partials/aaa/index.html',
                    controller: 'AAACtrl'});
                $routeProvider.when('/bbb', 
                   {templateUrl: config.base_url + 'app/partials/bbb/index.html', 
                    controller: 'BBBCtrl'});                   
                }]);
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, I thought about new routerProvider but stuck with sharing factory. Thank you :)